# Can assigning a name to a lambda impact performance?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda, auto

What is the difference in terms of performance, if any, between using a lambda directly and defining a named lambda and then passing it as an argument?

For example this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
```

versus this:

```
auto a_greater_than_b = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), a_greater_than_b);
```

Comment: have you tried to compile both and check the resulting assembly code for differences?

Comment: Have you heard of the Compiler Explorer? It allows you to see the assembly for a given piece of code. In this case, there is no difference in the assembly (there's a change of `x == y` becoming `y == x`, but that's not really a difference): https://godbolt.org/z/iBmO0M

Comment: A reasonable compiler will generate equivalent asm. There's rarely a difference between a temporary and declared variable. This discounts variables assigned to a non-moveable temporary, in which case there may be a legitimate performance benefit to passing a temporary arg without declaring a variable for it (sometimes... depends on the compiler and environment). When writing new code that needs to be performant, i'd be more concerned with things like making sure you avoid cache misses, or other horrible bottlenecks by profiling often.

Comment: And a tangent note: involving a `std::function` object would make it considerably less likely you would get the same assembly/performance as the two cases compared here.

Comment: You can compare the assembly on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rmjLq3)

Answer (score 6):

Using  [gcc 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/be9F9A) with following code:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });


    auto a_greater_than_b = [](int a, int b) { return a < b; };
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), a_greater_than_b);
}
```

Outputs for the nameless:

```
main::{lambda(int, int)#1}::operator()(int, int) const:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  movl %esi, -12(%rbp)
  movl %edx, -16(%rbp)
  movl -12(%rbp), %eax
  cmpl -16(%rbp), %eax
  setg %al
  popq %rbp
  ret

.....

leaq -48(%rbp), %rax
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end()
  movq %rax, %rbx
  leaq -48(%rbp), %rax
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin()
  movq %rbx, %rsi
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call void std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main::{lambda(int, int)#1}, main::{lambda(int, int)#1})
```

and for the named one:

```
main::{lambda(int, int)#2}::operator()(int, int) const:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  movl %esi, -12(%rbp)
  movl %edx, -16(%rbp)
  movl -12(%rbp), %eax
  cmpl -16(%rbp), %eax
  setl %al
  popq %rbp
  ret

.....

leaq -48(%rbp), %rax
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end()
  movq %rax, %rbx
  leaq -48(%rbp), %rax
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin()
  movq %rbx, %rsi
  movq %rax, %rdi
  call void std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main::{lambda(int, int)#2}>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main::{lambda(int, int)#2}, main::{lambda(int, int)#2})
```

Both are the same. So no difference.

Comment: Normally when doing assembly comparisons, you should turn on optimizations, but it's interesting that there's no difference even without optimizations

Comment: I thought that if non optimized produces the same code, turning on the optimizations wouldn't probably change the result, since there isn't really anything that could result in different optimized code for the two cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's almost guaranteed (I'd be extremely surprised if you got different optimized code from identical unoptimized code). I just wanted to clarify that if someone were to see a difference between two pieces of code, if optimizations are turned off, that doesn't mean anything.